# JUnitXml format at GHUnit fraemwork

Tags: unit-testing, junit, gh-unit

Does anybody know how to create xml report as result of tests using GHUnit?

I do like that, but .xml file didn't appear...

GHUNIT_AUTORUN=1 WRITE_JUNIT_XML=YES xcodebuild -project Tests.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator4.3  -target Tests

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it stores the output in DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR which looks something like:

```
/var/folders/IY/IY7PGAf2F9OD6CIKr1RQo++++TI/-Tmp-/
```

If you check the RunScripts.sh file you can see it's saving to:

```
/usr/bin/getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the instruction set here:

http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/docs/appledoc_include/guide_command_line.html

You need to include the run test script as a phase after your build.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
GHUNIT_CLI=1 WRITE_JUNIT_XML=1 xcodebuild...
```

I think it's the '1' rather than 'YES' that makes it work.

The XML files end up in a build/test-results folder and form me it is relative to the project workspace.